# Advanced Approvals - Vendor Bill - dont get the Next Approver

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to implement the Advanced Approvals flow for the standalone Vendor Bill that we weren't using.

So, I'v enabled the workflow Advanced Approvals for Vendor Bill Transactions, I've enabled the Script Deployment for that kind of transactions and I've created the Advanced Approvals rules.

After that, I'm able to Submit the Vendor Bill. This shows that the workflow is detecting the transaction. But after submit the transaction, the "Next Approver" field stay blank and the Vendor Bill is automatically approved.

[image: Transaction without Next Approver]

[image: Workflow logs]

[image: EDIT: Advanced Approvals Rules]

Comment: Those flows are based off purchase limits. It only goes to the next approver if it is over the limit.

Comment: Hi! The minimum value was set to zero from booth approvers.